# Why did this wire in my dryer melt?

Tags: dryer

I have an electric Kenmore dryer, actual manufacturer appears to be Inglis - model number on the sticker says "C110-8240091", though that doesn't bring up much in my online searching.  It's been working fine since we bought it (used) 6 months ago.

Today it stopped heating, so I pulled it out, opened the back panel, and had a nice "well there's your problem" moment.

One of the wires on the temperature switch mounted to the bottom of the heating element has melted.  I can easily cut back the melted part of the wire, crimp on a new connector and plug it back in.

But first I really want to know what caused it to melt like that in the first place.  My guess is that it was poorly crimped, and had enough resistance to heat up and slowly melt the wire.  Does that make sense?

The thermal switch appears to be closed circuit, which is normal.  Anything else I should check for before repairing the wire and testing it out?

[image: Overview]
[image: Closeup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption.

Poor crimped connection lead to a high resistance join and heating over time causing the wire to melt.

Re Terminate with a new connector.

As an extra precaution check the resistance across the thermal cut out switch the resistance should be close to zero.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I experienced as well and it turned out when I slid the connector on and off that it was loose.  Clipped back to good wire, spliced in a little extra wire, sanded the male connector piece and put on a new connector.  Everything is working well several days later.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing the wire from a 12 AWG stranded to a 10 AWG stranded wire if your dryer draws 30 Amps. My 2008 Samsung dryer has 12 AWG and draws 30 Amps (a mistake long term, hence the change to the thicker wire)